# Export CSV File in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

there is a button on my settings that once clicked it will prompt to download a csv file. Here is the code.

```
<?php

/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'Members Log Data', 
                      'Members Log', 
                      'manage_options', 
                      'sj-member-option', 
                      'members_option' );
}

/** Step 3. */
function members_option() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  
    {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    $name = "member-log-".date('Y-m-d');
    $list[] = array('username','no of favorites');

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);

    $op = fopen('php://output','w');
    foreach($list as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($op,$row);
    }
    fclose($op);
    /*
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    */
}
```

I am getting can not modify session header.

I would like to ask how to do this in WP as I am familiar outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to send a `header` command too late, hence the error. Use the hook [`load-(your_page)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29) for this kind of output.

```
function my_plugin_menu() {
    $page = add_options_page( 'Members Log Data', 
                      'Members Log', 
                      'manage_options', 
                      'sj-member-option', 
                      'members_option' );
     add_action( "load-$page", 'do_export' );
}
```

In the `members_option` function callback add a `<form>` with a submit button and in the new `do_export` function you'll put the export actions. Something like bellow, note that I'm not checking for the nonce, but for security best practices you should do it instead of checking for `$_POST['submit']`.

```
function members_option() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  
    {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    ?>
        <form method='post' >
            <p class="submit">
                <?php wp_nonce_field('my-import'); ?>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Restore'/>
            </p>
        </form> 
    <?php 
}

function do_export() { 
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && 'Restore' == $_POST['submit'] )
    {
        $name = "member-log-".date('Y-m-d');
        $list[] = array('username','no of favorites');
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);

        $op = fopen('php://output','w');
        foreach($list as $row)
        {
            fputcsv($op,$row);
        }
        fclose($op);
    }
}
```

In my tests, the export result was an HTML file with the full contents of the page plus the `'username','no of favorites'` that you defined, but this is a matter for another question/research.